# SP2007: Change/Set permission for Folder possible as in SP10?

Tags: permissions, folder, library

I know in SP 2010 it is possible to set/change permission for folders in a library.
I dont have SP 2007 here, but is it there also possible to do that in the same way? Is it possible to add users with different permissions for a folder?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is very much possible. This is a by "design" feature that SharePoint Foundation provides us.

Follow these links for the same :
 http://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2007/11/27/permission-inheritance-and-folders/

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/manage-permissions-for-a-list-library-folder-document-or-list-item-HA010021564.aspx